# extjs how to add a chart label

Tags: charts, extjs

I have multiple charts with different label [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3jjc).

Instead of title, I would like to put that on the chart itself as overlay or something:

[image]

Ideally it should be sticky: it would stay centered with a 5px margin from the top, but would remain so even if the canvas is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add the sprite on one of the surfaces on the chart widget. I did this on box ready; there is a gotcha with canvas as things are not rendered right away, so any logic that depends on measurement needs a small delay to be accurate.